# access all array members in a loop

Tags: bash, shell-script

I've been playing around with scripting lately.. wrote this one with help of @Cas

```
#!/bin/bash


## Variables ##

host="`/bin/hostname`";


    ## Limits ##

OneMin="1";
FiveMin="6";
FifteenMin="6";

    ## Mail IDs ##

To="yousaf@itlinks.com, khalid@itlinks.com";
Fr="root@"$host;


    ## Load Averages ##

LA=(`uptime | grep -Eo '[0-9]+\.[0-9]+' | cut -d"." -f1`)


    ## Top Process List ##

tp=(`ps -ef | sort -nrk 3,3 | grep -E "(php|httpd)" | grep -v root | head -n30 | awk '{print $2}'`)


## Actions ##

if [ ${LA[0]} -ge $OneMin ]; then


    ## Send Mail ##

echo -e "From: $Fr
To: $To
Subject: *ALERT* - Current Load on '$host' Is High
Load Averages Are:  \n\n
1:Min\t5:Min\t15:Min   \n
${LA[0]}\t${LA[1]}\t${LA[2]}  \n\n

List Of Processes That Were Killed \n" | sendmail -t


    ## Kill Top Pocesses ##


for i in $tp ; do
    kill -9 $i
done



fi
```

I'm not sure if that array works, especially the last part, where I've added a loop to kill top processes.. cause it does not print list of process in that email. I have no clue why. But script does not give any error..

OK ## WORKAROUND ##

Btw, would this work?

```
#!/bin/bash


## Variables ##

host="`/bin/hostname`";


    ## Limits ##

OneMin="7";
FiveMin="6";
FifteenMin="6";


    ## Load Averages ##

LA=(`uptime | grep -Eo '[0-9]+\.[0-9]+' | cut -d"." -f1`)



## Actions ##


    ## One Minut Action ##

if [ ${LA[0]} -ge $OneMin ]; then


    ## Send Mail ##

echo -e "From: $Fr
To: $To
Subject: *ALERT* - Current Load on '$host' Is High
Load Averages Are:  \n\n
1:Min\t5:Min\t15:Min   \n
${LA[0]}\t${LA[1]}\t${LA[2]}  \n\n

List Of Processes That Were Killed \n
`ps -ef | sort -nrk 3,3 | grep -E "(php|httpd)" | grep -v root | head -n30 | awk '{print $2}'`" | sendmail -t


    ## Kill Top Pocesses ##


for i in `ps -ef | sort -nrk 3,3 | grep -E "(php|httpd)" | grep -v root | head -n30 | awk '{print $2}'` ; do
    kill -9 $i
done


fi
```

I mean would this kill all PiDs?

Comment: Also the $tp array command gives more PiDs when printed, but send only one PiD in the email, I guess it's not killing all the processes or just not reading variable again..

Comment: That's a terrible question title BTW

Comment: -> shellcheck.net

Comment: there are several problems with your script.  1. you're using backticks instead of $().  2. there should be a blank line after the Subject: line in your message.  3. You don't need `\n` characters inside the double-quoted string being piped to sendmail - just add more lines. 4. The loadavg value in `$LA[0]` is **always** going to be a floating point number, and shell doesn't do floating point arithmetic or comparisons. I'm surprised you're not getting an "integer expression expected" error message. 6. the for loop should be for `i in "${tp[@]}" ; do`.

Comment: 7. i can't tell what you're trying to do with that `ps` command.  why sort by PPID? Why grep for php as well as httpd? are you running php as a cgi interpreter rather than as a built-in apache module?

Comment: @cas Hi Cas, thanks for the notice, I think script works, cause it is generating emails & sending to the emails inserted in Fr variable. THE ONLY thing I'm concerned about is whether 2nd if statement would work if 1st if gets true? If you lnow what I mean, script should continue even if 1st if statement executes. 2nd I'm trying to minimize the load of a web server, if in case it gets an unexpected peak due to traffic influx. & yes php as a cgi interpreter. Now I think you have an idea, what I'm trying to achieve.

Comment: @cas Ok the final issue is, I'm trying to run this script now under cron.. Scrpt runs as needed, kills processes if load is high & generates email too. But if I set it to run under cron job, it doesn't give any desired output, No Email generated, No processes killed. I have no idea why..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that `tp=(...` defines an array but `$tp` references the first element of the array, only.

You need

```
for i in "${tp[@]}" ; do
```

Comment: I have pasted all the code I had written, in the question section. Can you please tell me if it kills all the PiDs now??

Comment: @Sollosa Shouldn't you be able to verify this yourself?